# Visual Studio 2010 - Events associated with a button are not being displayed in intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, intellisense

I am new to Visual Studio 2010, I have been in the dark ages (2005) for a long time.  It seems that I cannot just associate the "Click" event with any kind of server side button.  I can't see any of the "event" types for buttons (have not checked other control types, but assuming the same.

I see the following:
OnClientClick, but no "Click" or "OnClick"
Command, but no "OnCommand"

Strange, but I"m sure it's some config I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the MVC project from wrong perspective. There is no on-button click events in asp.net mvc Framework. What you have is `ActionResults` links.

However, if you want to place a button tag on view, then throw `JavaScript` you may simulate that event.

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
   document.location = '@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")';
});
```

If your **button is inside a Form** that you are posting, use this:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home")) {%>
```

**Solution #2:** For the case, if you have multiple buttons in your MVC view, then use this article for as an approach: [ASP.NET MVC – Multiple buttons in the same form](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx)

Comment: I see. I am using an sdk that requires it. But didn't really want my forms to adhere to that if at possible. What's interesting is that I started a new project, did not add in the MVC library, but am still seeing the same thing in that project as well. I did not do an MVC web application when I started the new project, only included that library in the first project. In my second project, there is no reference in the project to MVC from what I can tell and I'm still seeing the same thing.

Comment: what type of visual studio project did u create?  a ASP.NET Web Application or ASP.NET MVC Web application ?

Comment: Is there anyway that I can include the System.Http.Net library (just for my required SDK calls), but have my forms adhere to the classic asp/vb.net?

Comment: asp.net web application in both cases

Comment: if your can reference that file it should be picked up by namespaces and work fine. In any case, i have listed options that you may use from. In your case, you may wanna ho the javascript suggestion.

Comment: This is actually happening with visual studio 2003, 2005 on the same dev machine.  This is not good...  Something is screwed up on my dev machine since I installed asp.net mvc